# Using geometry nodes to calculate curve angle

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]I am currently trying to make a race track generator with geometry nodes and I came to a halt because I don't really understand how I can calculate the turn angle in various points of the curve and set a threshold for where to put kerbs and run offs.
I haven't really been able to find any resource on it and using the sample curve tangent hasn't yielded any results so far.
I started with a drawn curve that then i resampled, converted to a mesh and then extruded.
Thank you very much.

The grease pencil lines are where ideally the kerbs should go.

Comment: So, you want to get an approximation if curvature in XY (not including up/down).. or ore there other constraints on these features?

Comment: can you please add a sketch/image, what angle you are talking of?

Comment: the constraints are only X and Y, the only other constraint is the turn angle, Ideally I would like to be able to control the depth of each kerbs based on how narrow the angle is.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can calculate a signed angle for each point of a curve:

[image]

It doesn't use *Tangents*, so the angle is clearly defined as an angle between the evaluated line segments:

- segment 1: between the previous point and currently evaluated point
- segment 2: between currently evaluated point, and the next point

The angle is $0$ if either segment is missing because it's the first or the last point. If you want an angle spanning across multiple points, just pass the calculated value to *Accumulate Field* node, capture it again, and now you can compare currently evaluated point's value with any other point to check the angle between those.

Comment: sorry, why are the two offset point in curve different? Also I plugged it in the original geometry but it doesnt seem to be working. What do i need to plug in the point index?

Comment: *"why are the two offset point in curve different"* - one represents the previous point, one the next point. This is why one has negative offset, one positive. *"it doesnt seem to be working."* - it's not clear what your geometry is exactly and how you want it to work exactly. Maybe upload your .blend file using https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: my geometry currently is a bezier curve, my current goal is to be able to add an additional extrusion along the side of the track but only in the areas where there is a turn that meets a specific threshold in order to create the kerbs.

Comment: Resample Curve, "Evaluated" mode.