How much is curve curved along its factor
I am finding a way how to get this value the best way, any ideas please?
Some kind of a total value per curve. (I need to exclude curves that are curved to much in my GN setup)

thanks Quellenform, I think it works, with the curve handle angles better for the 3d curves.



Might be helpful to share the .blend file.

Might be helpful too: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/302909/145249

thanks Quellenform

you need to modify linked algorithm to use normal in the cross product, and to accumulate the angle of all points.

I suppose you can use curve tangent for this. Normal node is not good for this because it depends on curve twist.

Then you make a dot product of two nearest curve point tangents, then use arccosine node to calculate angle from dot product.

even better, thanks!
